# Mod in Java produces negative numbers

Tags: java, math, modulo

When I calculate `int i = -1 % 2`  I get `-1` in Java. In Python, I  get `1` as the result of `-1 % 2`.
What do I have to do to get the same behavior in Java with the modulo function?

Comment: Wait, this is actually a duplicate question. It also has a perfect answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412200/1083704

Comment: @Val you mentioned modulo n equivalence classes: this range {0,1,2..n-1} is good for programmers, but {-n,n+1,n+2,-1} is equivalent and has the same right to exist

Comment: No doubt part of the confusion stems from our colloquial name "mod" for this operator (leftover from the C family?), when the Java documentation actually calls it the "remainder" operator (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: K&R C defines the `%` operator as producing the **remainder**, but names it the **modulus** operator. Confusingly, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation says that the *modulo* operation produces the **remainder**, both in computing and in mathematics... but also claims "The range of numbers for an integer modulo of n is 0 to n − 1."!

Comment: There is no modulus operator in Java. % is a remainder operator.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The problem here is that in Python the % operator returns the **modulus** and in Java it returns the **remainder**.  These functions give the same values for positive arguments, but the modulus always returns positive results for negative input, whereas the remainder may give negative results.  There's some more information about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder).

You can find the positive value by doing this:

```
int i = (((-1 % 2) + 2) % 2)
```

or this:

```
int i = -1 % 2;
if (i<0) i += 2;
```

(obviously -1 or 2 can be whatever you want the numerator or denominator to be)

Comment: will only work in n%m if abs(n) < m

Comment: @amit_gr - no I believe it works in general

Comment: you are right - my mistake. +1

Comment: I'd just like to make clear that this only works for negative dividends.

A general solution will require a conditional expression:
(a < 0) ? ((a % b) + b) % b : (a % b)

Comment: @Cachapa please provide an example to support that statement.  I believe the OP's solution is general already, consider that `(((-3 % 4) + 4) % 4) = 1` (the intended result) and also that `(((3 % 4) + 4) % 4) = 3` (also the intended result).  It works with both positive and negative dividends.

Comment: @The111 Imagine the range of your integer is [-8, 7], (((5 % 6) + 6) % 6) = ((5 + 6) % 6) = (-5 % 6) = -5, but 5 % 6 is supposed to be positive. Substitute appropriately large numbers for 32 bit ints like 536887296 and 1610612736 and it is clear the second method is the better one.

Comment: @Greg Rogers fair enough. I hadn't considered overflow (nor had it been mentioned prior to your post). Thanks for the insight!

Comment: It isn't the modulus, it's the remainder. Fix your answer.

Comment: I don't know why everyone up-voted this, but it is wrong in JDK8 at least. example -5 % 3 gives -2, not -1, so the "if (i<0) i += m" trick is not relevant. We should be doing abs(result) to get the correct answer

Comment: actually ignore my comment above, I didn't realize the OP was trying to replicate python, I thought he/she just wanted the positive equivalent

Comment: Considering n % m where n < m, why not just use: **(n + m) % m**?

Comment: @pgreze imagine the case where `n=-1000` and `m=3`, the correct answer would be `2`, but in your formula the answer is still negative.

Comment: faster, as shifting, masking, and adding are significantly faster than a second % op (and even moreso vs the conditional branch):  `int remainder = (x % n); return (remainder >> 31) & n + n;`

Comment: = ( value % 2 ) & 1

Comment: I'm confused regarding the second `%`. Why not just `((n % m) + m)`? This should also give the positive modulo no?

Comment: @csstudent1418 That will break in case where `n` is positive, returning a result `> m`

Comment: This answer alludes the reader that the result will always be positive, but consider `int n = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and now try `((1 % n) + n) % n` The overflow results in `-1 % n` = -1.  Where you expect `1 + n % n` = 1.  Also--distinguishing between a remainder and a modulus class in this way is a bit misleading. A remainder is equal to the smallest element of the modulus class. The difference is that Python does normal _moding_ where `5 => {[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]}` where Java does symmetric moding `5 => {[-2], [-1], [0], [1], [2]}`.

Answer (score 152):

**Since Java 8** you can use the [Math.floorMod()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) method:

```
Math.floorMod(-1, 2); //== 1
```

Note: If the modulo-value (here `2`) is negative, all output values will be negative too. :)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830153/2311557

Answer (score 2):

If you need `n % m` then:

```
int i = (n < 0) ? (m - (abs(n) % m) ) %m : (n % m);
```

mathematical explanation:

```
n = -1 * abs(n)
-> n % m = (-1 * abs(n) ) % m
-> (-1 * (abs(n) % m) ) % m
-> m - (abs(n) % m))
```

Comment: This expression didn't work for me. For negative values I was getting values between 1:m instead of the expected 0:m-1, as in the case where n is positive. The solution from andrewmu functioned as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
if b > 0:
    int mod = (mod = a % b) < 0 ? a + b : a;
```

Doesn't use the `%` operator twice.

Comment: How does the speed of this compare to the version with two % operators?

Comment: That's a good question. I perform a lot of premature optimization. I assume it saves a couple of CPU cycles.

Comment: @Dice : If you make a good case that this solution is better than the currently accepted solution, that would be valuable for people who browse this question.

Comment: Whether an `if` is faster than a `%` depends on your CPU and the data you feed it, due to branch prediction--`if`s are faster if the condition has a predictable pattern.

Comment: This is almost certainly slower because it  has a branch, unless you know that the input will mostly be positive.  If its random, then the branch prediction penalty will cost more clock cycles than an extra remainder calculation on most CPUs.  Or, if you want to conditionally add a value based on whether an int is negative or not, try `(maybeNegative >> 31) ^ thingToMaybeAdd + thingToAddTo`

Answer (score 1):

If the modulus is a power of 2 then you can use a bitmask:

```
int i = -1 & ~-2; // -1 MOD 2 is 1
```

By comparison the Pascal language provides two operators; REM takes the sign of the numerator (`x REM y` is `x - (x DIV y) * y` where `x DIV y` is `TRUNC(x / y)`) and MOD requires a positive denominator and returns a positive result.