# Changing least significant bit in pixel

Tags: vb.net

I need to set the least significant bits of some bytes (from an image).

For example, I have an image of width w and height h. Each element [w][h] is a pixel.

Sample data for the red channel (where I want to set the bits):

> [0][0] = 0101011**1**
>   [0][1] = 0101011**0**
>   [0][2] = 0101111**0**
>   [0][3] = 1111101**1**
>   [0][4] = 0101101**0**
>   [0][5] = 0110011**0**
>   [0][6] = 0101010**1**
>   [0][7] = 1101010**1**

I want to change the bits in bold text into 00101010.

My code so far:

```
  Dim img As New Bitmap(TextBox1.Text)

    For w As Integer = 0 To img.Width - 1
        For h As Integer = 0 To img.Height - 1
            Dim pixel As Color = img.GetPixel(w, h)

            If w < 4 AndAlso h < TextBox2.Text.Length Then
                Dim pix As Integer = pixel.R
                Dim pix2bin As String = Convert.ToString(pix, 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I somewhat re-wrote your question to make it clearer. If you feel it does not represent what you wanted to ask, please feel free to edit it further.

Comment: You might find [Changing lsb value of image rgb value giving inconsistent value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26616856/1115360) to be of use.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your comment  "I need to change the last bit", what you need to do is take the byte from the image, set its lowest bit to zero (`And &FE`), extract the appropriate bit from the byte you want to set the lowest bits to (shift right `>>` and `And` with 1) then `Or` them together:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' {&H57, &H56, &H5e, &Hfb, &H5a, &H66, &H55, &Hd5}
        Dim bb As Byte() = {&B1010111, &B1010110, &B1011110, &B11111011, &B1011010, &B1100110, &B1010101, &B11010101}
        Dim lowestBits As Byte = &B101010 ' &H2A

        ' output before state:
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", bb.Select(Function(b) Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c))))

        Dim bitPosition = 7
        For i = 0 To bb.Length - 1
            bb(i) = CByte((bb(i) And &HFE) Or ((lowestBits >> bitPosition) And 1))
            bitPosition = (bitPosition + 7) Mod 8 ' equivalent to subtract one and keep it in the range [0, 7]
        Next

        ' output after state:
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", bb.Select(Function(b) Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"c))))
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
01010111 01010110 01011110 11111011 01011010 01100110 01010101 11010101
01010110 01010110 01011111 11111010 01011011 01100110 01010101 11010100
```

You didn't say which way you wanted to set the bits from the replacement, so I did it by using the highest bit from the values-to-set-it-to for the first byte. Modify the code appropriately if you want them the other way round.

You *really* do not want to convert bytes to strings to perform bit operations on them because it will be very slow.

[I used VS 2017 RC for the convenience of binary literals - I included comments for hex format for you to test this.]