# Math question: how to know if coordinate is in 'row'?

Tags: java, math

I have a bit hard to explain question but I'll try to do my best.
I need a function to check if a random coordinate is in a 'row'.

An image to explain:[image]

Let's say **size = 20** and **between = 100**
There are a endless amount of rows. And the coordinates are always an int (so are size & between)

How to chenk if a random coordinate is in a row or in the 'between' zone?
I call this method very often on the main thread of a program (not allowed to use aSync), what is the best/most efficient way to do this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What's your definition of coordinate? (Is it an `int`, a `double`, a pair of doubles?) And what do you mean by "row"? Those look like columns to me; I thought rows were horizontal.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you provide multiple examples with corresponding expected results.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for helping! My coordinate's are int's, sorry for not explaining it in the question (will edit). And yes I mean columns.

Comment: @user3682563 Thanks! Someone else already added an answer which I will test, so if that answer is right, I will accept it but if it is not, I will make multiple examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify, the following assumes that you want the boundaries of [0, size] to be included in the "row".  If not, update the `<=` accordingly.

First we can handle the case of the first row:

```
boolean isInFirstRow = 0 <= i && i <= size;
```

Now we update to handle the repeating nature of the rows:

```
int positionWithinSection = i % (size + between);
boolean isInRow = 0 <= positionWithinSection && positionWithinSection <= size;
```

Minor optimization: Since we are using mod, we know `positionWithinSection` will always be positive.  And since each "row" begins at the start of each section, we don't have to check the lower bound at all:

```
int positionWithinSection = i % (size + between);
boolean isInRow = positionWithinSection <= size;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed `positionWithinSection <= size` to `positionWithinSection < size` and `i <= size` to `i < size` and now it works almost perfectly for me! The only thing I am trying to do is to let it also work with negative coordinates. Will post it if I did it :)

Comment: Got it fully working now! For the people wondering: `isInFirstRow` isn't needed and in Java % returns the remainder not the modulo so `if(positionWithinSection < 0) positionWithinSection += (size + between);` will work ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385024/mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers)).

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to establish length of period which is size + between.
Than you need to take a phase in this period by taking % from length.
Finally by investigating the modulo part you will know where in cycle you are.

`Am I between given (between, size, coordinate)?:
    lenght := size + between
    positionInCycle := coordinate % length
    if(size > positionInCicle) return false
    other case, return true`

Also note that if you don't start with "size" but rather a portion of a gap you can manipulate the answer by simply "renumbering" coordinates saying coordinate = coordinate - startlength of gap

Also it is worth noting that if you want the code to work with coordinates lower than 0 it is worth checking how exactly modulo works for negative numbers. And also there is one border condition in which both the between and size are 0 in which case the % operation is not well defined.