# This equation gives different result in "Python" and "Java"

Tags: java, python

I am converting a program written in **Python** to **Java**. There is an equation in **Python** code: `(19 - 20) % 91` and it **Java** version is `(19 - 20) % 91` means same. This equation is giving the answer **90** in **Python** but, in **Java** it is giving the answer **-1**. How do I modify this equation from **Python** to **Java** so that it can work and run properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mod in Java produces negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385024/mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers)

Comment: look that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385024/mod-in-java-produces-negative-numbers

Comment: The java code already runs properly, according to the definition of the java language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in Python the % operator returns the **modulus** and in Java it returns the **remainder**. These functions give the same values for positive arguments, but the modulus always returns positive results for negative input, whereas the remainder may give negative results. There's some more information about it in this question.

You can find the positive value by doing this:

```
int i = (19-20) % 91;
if (i<0) i += 91;
```

Or you can use [Math.floorMod()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-):

```
Math.floorMod((19-20), 91);
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! 