# Opposite of numpy.unwrap

Tags: python, numpy

In Python numpy, there is an [unwrap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) function that:

> Unwrap radian phase p by changing absolute jumps greater than discont
>   to their 2*pi complement along the given axis.

Now, I'd like to do the opposite function. How can I *wrap* an array of phases? E.g. how to convert all angles to constraint them between -π and π?

The obvious way would be to do something like:

```
for i, a in enumerate(phases):
    while a < pi:
        a += 2 * pi
    while a > pi:
        a -= 2 * pi
    phases[i] = a
```

but is there a simpler / faster way?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
phases = (phases + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi) - np.pi
```

Comment: I didn't realized I could use the % operator with floating point values. But why are you adding π before performing the modulus?

Comment: because that's needed if you need your result to be between (-np.pi,np.pi) instead of (0,2*np.pi).  If you don't add it, but just subtract , 0 will be mapped into -> -np.pi which is incorrect

Comment: It's obvious! I feel stupid now... I didn't realize it because I'm only interested in relative phase, and wasn't taking attention to the absolute phase.

Comment: what is the difference between this answer and just using `np.unwrap(phases)`?  Is there a case i'm missing where the following test would return False? `np.allclose(np.unwrap(phases),(phases + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi ) - np.pi)`

Comment: @Fnord, that's not what `np.unwrap` does at all.  You can test it yourself -- generate an array of random numbers in `[-pi, pi)`, and call `unwrap` on it.  You'll get an array that does not, in general, stay in `[-pi, pi)`.

Comment: @jsw sorry i misread the doc, `unwrap` looks for jumps in a sequence where the OP wants everything contained within a range, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Hmm, there's no convenience function for this?

Answer (score 13):

```
import numpy as np
phases = np.arctan2(np.sin(phases), np.cos(phases))
```

This works because sin(phases)/cos(phases) == tan(phases).  We get back phases (modulo 2π) by using the inverse-tangent function.  Mathematically, the inverse-tangent function is multivalued, so in programming languages it is usually defined to return the phase in a fixed interval.

The two-parameter arctangent function, i.e. `np.arctan2(numerator, denominator)`, is the same as the regular arctangent function except that it keeps track of the signs of the numerator and denominator, and therefore is able to return the phase modulo 2π, instead of the regular `np.arctan(numerator/denominator)` function which is only able to return the phase modulo π.  Numpy's implementation of the `arctan2` function is defined to return the phase in the range [-π, +π], which is the range that the OP requested.

Additional explanation: This arctan2 method follows directly from the complex representation, and is entirely mathematically equivalent to:

```
phases = np.angle(np.exp(1j*phases))
```

which may be more intuitive.  And in fact, numpy's `angle` function uses `arctan2` behind the scenes to separate the imaginary and real components of the exponential, i.e. the sine and cosine.

Comment: Please explain your answers. The OP is more likely to understand your answer with a few sentences.

Comment: Interresting, but probably very inefficient... But I give you upvote for the well written answer.

Comment: I agree that this is slower than using the `%` operator, but it is more intuitive for me (but maybe I'm the only one) because it follows straightforwardly from the complex-number representation, see edit.  Furthermore, I don't  have to think hard about whether python's `%` operator keeps the sign of the divisor or the dividend and how this affects the result, or whether I have to add and then subtract a constant before and after performing the mod operation in order to keep the resulting phase in the range I want.

Comment: @CharlesBrunet I have quickly tested it on my machine: `phases = 3 * np.pi * (np.random.random(1000) - 0.5)`
_The modulo approach is 6 times faster_ for this example:
`%timeit phases_modulo = (phases + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi) - np.pi
10.1 µs ± 43.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`
`%timeit phases_arctan = np.arctan2(np.sin(phases), np.cos(phases))
61.2 µs ± 304 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

Comment: I like this method better... it's a shame it's more inefficient.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is a slight variation to sega_sai answer which is:

```
phases = ( phases + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi ) - np.pi
```

This maps phases to [-pi, pi) -> which means pi is mapped to -pi

Shown here:

```
In [27]: phases = np.pi

In [28]: phases = ( phases + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi ) - np.pi

In [29]: print phases
-3.14159265359
```

Which is perfectly legitimate but if you want a mapping of (-pi, pi] then

Times the input and output of the operation buy -1. Like so:

```
phases =  (( -phases + np.pi) % (2.0 * np.pi ) - np.pi) * -1.0
```

Comment: Even though in measured data, it's pretty unlikely to hit exactly this Lebesgue zero set with angle = pi, still it's a cool solution to map it to the other half open interval.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar to the suggested functions here in my utility library [haggis](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The function [`haggis.math.ang_diff_min`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.math.ang_diff_min) does exactly what you want. You can set the definition of a full circle manually, which is nice in case you want to use degrees or grads or any other arbitrary angular measure:

```
 ang_diff_min(phases, 0)
```