# Standard way to normalize an angle to +/- π radians in Java

Tags: java, radians

Is there a library function or a well-known quick efficient way in Java to normalize an angle to +/- π — e.g. when adding two angles?

What I've got now (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323034/27358)) is basically the code below...

```
private static final double TWO_PI = 2 * Math.PI;

double normalize(double theta) {
    double normalized = theta % TWO_PI;
    normalized = (normalized + TWO_PI) % TWO_PI;
    return normalized <= Math.PI ? normalized : normalized - TWO_PI;
}
```

...but it seems a little complicated and performance-wise I'm not excited about the modulo operator. (Note that I can't guarantee `theta` isn't some relatively large number, so I don't think there's a pure addition/subtraction solution without looping. I don't actually know how a hand-rolled loop is likely to compare to `%`.)

Is there a well-tested optimized library function I can use, or a better algorithm, or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: You're trying to round to the nearest 90 degree (half pi) or the nearest 180 degree (full pi)?

Comment: @Kon 180 degree / full pi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to keeping angles between -179 and 180 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320986/easy-way-to-keeping-angles-between-179-and-180-degrees)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I've read that answer but given that most Java math / geometry libraries are in radians it seems plausible that there's a better answer working in radians than in degrees.

Comment: ...and in fact @CupawnTae has provided a [library function answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24234924/27358).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apache commons has one:

[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/util/MathUtils.html#normalizeAngle(double, double)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/util/MathUtils.html#normalizeAngle(double,%20double))

> normalize an angle between -π and +π
>
> `a = MathUtils.normalizeAngle(a, 0.0);`

And looking at the source code, you could reproduce it with this (they use their own `FastMath.floor` but in case you want to do it without an external library):

```
theta - TWO_PI * Math.floor((theta + Math.PI) / TWO_PI)
```

Source is here: https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/53ec46ba272e23c0c96ada42f26f4e70e96f3115/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/util/MathUtils.java#L107

---

**Note for readers from the future**: this method has just (June 2017) [been removed](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/commit/6f27b4ae8f8ecb62698e760ab7df3973874b1f51) from the latest commons-math 4.x codebase. If you're using a version after this, you'll want to use [commons-numbers](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-numbers/) instead (once it's released) - currently:

```
a = PlaneAngleRadians.normalizeBetweenMinusPiAndPi(a);
```

or

```
a = PlaneAngleRadians.normalize(a, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 17):

There is only one 100% foolproof way:

```
public static double normalizeAngle(double angle) {
    return Math.atan2(Math.sin(angle), Math.cos(angle));
}
```

Everything else is people trying to be too smart and failing.

Comment: This method is probably more accurate (and I think provides a half-closed range, unlike `MathUtils`), but it's also about 40x slower (median ~190ns on my 15" MBP, vs. ~4.9ns using `MathUtils`), which may be more important for some applications.

Comment: I agree, atan2 can be slow. But it handles cases with NaN and ±Infinity.

Comment: MathUtils handles those as well -- it returns NaN for all three, just as atan2 does.

Comment: This method has weird artifacts at certain angles. I was never able to get it to work 100% foolproof even though it works in theory.

Comment: Foolproof? May be, I don't know. But constraining an arithmetic value within arithmetic bounds by using *three* trigonometric functions seems like overkill to me. A couple of while() statements would be just as safe (coupled with a single if() for fringe cases).

Comment: The range for the result is from -PI to +PI, I would like something from 0 to 2xPI